# Javascript hoisting - cant understand this

Tags: javascript, hoisting, executioncontext

Trying to learn Js and cant understand why DOM element doesn't get the value:

```
var Car = function(loc) {
  var obj = Object.create(Car.prototype);
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = move;
  return obj;
};

Car.prototype = {
    move : function() {
    this.loc++;
  }
};

var emy = Car(1);
emy.move();

document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = emy.loc;
```

So I create a class constructor and its prototype object, but the last line - `document.getElementById("id").innerHTML = emy.loc;` is not being executed (unless I put it in the top of the file). Why is that?

Snippet:

https://jsfiddle.net/awj6mf1b/

Comment: yes I just named its id "id" :) Sorry for confusion

Comment: can you create a codepen/snippet which replicates your issue by editing your question and pressing the snippet button

Comment: Added. As you see frst gets undefined but second div has no value at all..

Comment: Thanks @Sergio Tulentsev - I will keep this in mind

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You haven't defined what move is:

```
var Car = function(loc) {
  var obj = Object.create(Car.prototype);
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = move;  // <<< Here
  return obj;
};
```

Giving the error:

```
Uncaught ReferenceError: move is not defined
    at Car (VM52:51)
    at window.onload (VM52:61)
```

You can fix this by just putting the function in your object during instatiation:

```
var Car = function(loc) {
  var obj = Object.create(Car.prototype);
  obj.loc = loc;
  obj.move = function() {
    this.loc++;
  }
  return obj;
};
```

Or by correctly adding the function to the prototype:

```
var Car = function(loc) {
  var obj = Object.create(Car.prototype);
  obj.loc = loc;
  // Removed move from here
  return obj;
};

// This adds move to the cars prototype
Car.prototype.move = function() {
  this.loc++;
}
```

Comment: Ah, yeah, ok. I could also keep my pattern `Car.prototype = {
 move : function() {
   this.loc++;
  }
};` Just needed to remove `obj.move = move` from the constructor...

Comment: @rordevnewb yes, sorry I slightly changed the syntax for adding the function to the constructor but there's no reason to not use yours, the problem was the reference to `move` in the constructor.

Comment: Yes, I understand - I am just learning and this pattern was used when Netscape ruled the world :)  Thanks for explanation!

Answer (score 1):

> is not being executed (unless I put it in the top of the file)

Usually that indicates presence of errors in code above. The code crashes before it can execute this line.

Inspect the console log of that fiddle and you'll see.

Oh, and hoisting has nothing to do with what's happening here.

Comment: Thanks, now I understand it